# webview_flutter in not working getting a platform error

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile-development

am trying to activate the payment gateway in my app.  after getting all data needed to open the payment page ( this includes all necessary data like token first name.... etc. ) .  after that I should display a page. in this page the user must enter his card info.

my issue is:  when trying to or when trying to open page  using the WebView()  am getting error like
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Platform view hasn't been initialized from the platform view channel.

I have already added the permission of using the internet in the manifesto file.

also, i set the minSdkVersion  to 19 & compileSdkVersion 32 . in addention to that i run the flutter clean many times but this did not solve the issue .

my code  below :

```
    import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

import '../../shared/components/components.dart';
import '../../shared/components/const.dart';

class VisaCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const VisCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VisCard> createState() => _VisCardState();
}

class _VisCardState extends State<VisCard> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
  Completer<WebViewController>();

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl:"https://xxxxxxx/api/acceptance/iframes/684162?payment_token=${paymobFinalTokenCard}",
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
        // onProgress: (int progress) {
        //   print('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
        // },
        javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
          _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
        },
        onPageFinished: (String url) {
          print('Page finished loading: $url');
        },
        gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0x00000000),
      ),
    );

  }
  JavascriptChannel _toasterJavascriptChannel(BuildContext context) {
    return JavascriptChannel(
        name: 'Toaster',
        onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
          showSnackBar(context,message.toString() );

        });
  }
}
```

error message :

```
    [WARNING:dns_config_service_android.cc(153)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
      D/EGL_emulation( 8941): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f336f68cf90: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f359bd14080) 
  (first time)
**E/flutter ( 8941): [ERROR:flutter/fml/platform/android/jni_util.cc(204)] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Platform view hasn't been initialized from the platform view channel.**
E/flutter ( 8941):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController.initializePlatformViewIfNeeded(PlatformViewsController.java:732)
E/flutter ( 8941):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController.onDisplayPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:791)
E/flutter ( 8941):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.onDisplayPlatformView(FlutterJNI.java:1380)
E/flutter ( 8941):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 8941):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/flutter ( 8941):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:161)
E/flutter ( 8941):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/flutter ( 8941):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
E/flutter ( 8941):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 8941):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/flutter ( 8941):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
E/flutter ( 8941): 
F/flutter ( 8941): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1469)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env). 
F/libc    ( 8941): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 8941 (ample.paymobone), pid 8941 (ample.paymobone)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone64_x86_64/emulator64_x86_64_arm64:12/SE1A.211212.001.B1/8023802:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86_64'
Timestamp: 2022-10-18 02:10:20.176569800+0300
Process uptime: 0s
Cmdline: com.example.paymobone
pid: 8941, tid: 8941, name: ample.paymobone  >>> com.example.paymobone <<<
uid: 10160
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1469)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env). 
'
    rax 0000000000000000  rbx 00000000000022ed  rcx 00007f357d3205cf  rdx 0000000000000006
    r8  00007ffee229c9d0  r9  00007ffee229c9d0  r10 00007ffee229c970  r11 0000000000000217
    r12 00007f334f6d4bf0  r13 00007ffee229cad0  r14 00007ffee229c968  r15 00000000000022ed
    rdi 00000000000022ed  rsi 00000000000022ed
    rbp 0000000000000007  rsp 00007ffee229c960  rip 00007f357d3205cf
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000005e5cf  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+191) (BuildId: 5db8d317d3741b337ef046540bbdd0f7)
      #01 pc 000000000160bf95  /data/app/~~MrR5iAtJNiBzJu6ee3Fmmg==/com.example.paymobone-cvQMP3KIgkxZaQO8P_dSzg==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9292ed7a57d628289a096bc46aa71468ce209e08)
      #02 pc 0000000001631394  /data/app/~~MrR5iAtJNiBzJu6ee3Fmmg==/com.example.paymobone-cvQMP3KIgkxZaQO8P_dSzg==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9292ed7a57d628289a096bc46aa71468ce209e08)
      #03 pc 00000000016183d6  /data/app/~~MrR5iAtJNiBzJu6ee3Fmmg==/com.example.paymobone-cvQMP3KIgkxZaQO8P_dSzg==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9292ed7a57d628289a096bc46aa71468ce209e08)
      #04 pc 0000000001d847d9  /data/app/~~MrR5iAtJNiBzJu6ee3Fmmg==/com.example.paymobone-cvQMP3KIgkxZaQO8P_dSzg==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9292ed7a57d628289a096bc46aa71468ce209e08)
      #05 pc 00000000019b6578  /data/app/~~MrR5iAtJNiBzJu6ee3Fmmg==/com.example.paymobone-cvQMP3KIgkxZaQO8P_dSzg==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9292ed7a57d628289a096bc46aa71468ce209e08)
      #06 pc 00000000019b506a  /data/app/~~MrR5iAtJNiBzJu6ee3Fmmg==/com.example.paymobone-cvQMP3KIgkxZaQO8P_dSzg==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9292ed7a57d628289a096bc46aa71468ce209e08)
      #07 pc 00000000019b5be3  /data/app/~~MrR5iAtJNiBzJu6ee3Fmmg==/com.example.paymobone-cvQMP3KIgkxZaQO8P_dSzg==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9292ed7a57d628289a096bc46aa71468ce209e08)
      #08 pc 00000000019b6b0d  /data/app/~~MrR5iAtJNiBzJu6ee3Fmmg==/com.example.paymobone-cvQMP3KIgkxZaQO8P_dSzg==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9292ed7a57d628289a096bc46aa71468ce209e08)
      #09 pc 00000000019b553b  /data/app/~~MrR5iAtJNiBzJu6ee3Fmmg==/com.example.paymobone-cvQMP3KIgkxZaQO8P_dSzg==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9292ed7a57d628289a096bc46aa71468ce209e08)
      #10 pc 00000000019b5234  /data/app/~~MrR5iAtJNiBzJu6ee3Fmmg==/com.example.paymobone-cvQMP3KIgkxZaQO8P_dSzg==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9292ed7a57d628289a096bc46aa71468ce209e08)
      #11 pc 00000000019b6d9c  /data/app/~~MrR5iAtJNiBzJu6ee3Fmmg==/com.example.paymobone-cvQMP3KIgkxZaQO8P_dSzg==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9292ed7a57d628289a096bc46aa71468ce209e08)
      #12 pc 0000000001631f33  /data/app/~~MrR5iAtJNiBzJu6ee3Fmmg==/com.example.paymobone-cvQMP3KIgkxZaQO8P_dSzg==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9292ed7a57d628289a096bc46aa71468ce209e08)
      #13 pc 000000000163734a  /data/app/~~MrR5iAtJNiBzJu6ee3Fmmg==/com.example.paymobone-cvQMP3KIgkxZaQO8P_dSzg==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9292ed7a57d628289a096bc46aa71468ce209e08)
      #14 pc 0000000000018475  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+1013) (BuildId: 0b21e18f17c36471b0becec44f99518b)
      #15 pc 000000000001801e  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+126) (BuildId: 0b21e18f17c36471b0becec44f99518b)
      #16 pc 000000000015d253  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int)+35) (BuildId: f90004a78069fa4c4e587a2081d386cd)
      #17 pc 00000000001ab568  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+120) (BuildId: 5ead3b6496eb4808298a4612fe10561bbd30f354)
      #18 pc 0000000002003e6e  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+206)
      #19 pc 0000000002007082  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.Looper.loopOnce+162)
      #20 pc 0000000000395376  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+806) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #21 pc 000000000041da09  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+233) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #22 pc 00000000005a335c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+428) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #23 pc 000000000059d16c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1036) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #24 pc 000000000097c172  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1410) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #25 pc 000000000037e899  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+25) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #26 pc 000000000044d768  /system/framework/framework.jar
      #27 pc 000000000097c90d  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+3357) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #28 pc 000000000037e899  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+25) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #29 pc 00000000001c85ca  /system/framework/framework.jar
      #30 pc 0000000000594b42  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool)+306) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #31 pc 0000000000959a6f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1007) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #32 pc 00000000003a04bc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+140) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #33 pc 0000000000395376  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+806) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #34 pc 000000000041da09  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+233) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #35 pc 0000000000819502  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (_jobject* art::InvokeMethod<(art::PointerSize)8>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1442) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #36 pc 0000000000772728  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+56) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #37 pc 00000000000b5a30  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/x86_64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+144) (BuildId: d92cc57761604ac2f5849e74a41f38bf70ac7a09)
      #38 pc 0000000000395014  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+756) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #39 pc 000000000041d9fa  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+218) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #40 pc 00000000005a335c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+428) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #41 pc 000000000059d16c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1036) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #42 pc 000000000096e305  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1349) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #43 pc 000000000037e719  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #44 pc 000000000024800e  /system/framework/framework.jar
      #45 pc 0000000000594b42  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool)+306) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #46 pc 0000000000959a6f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1007) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #47 pc 00000000003a04bc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+140) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #48 pc 00000000008b3621  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2049) (BuildId: 5ead3b6496eb4808298a4612fe10561bbd30f354)
      #49 pc 0000000000395376  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+806) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #50 pc 000000000041da09  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+233) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #51 pc 0000000000819eb1  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, __va_list_tag*)+465) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #52 pc 00000000006ce8ac  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, __va_list_tag*)+620) (BuildId: cfc3de5d1c7b2855effeb77a784fc353)
      #53 pc 00000000000c6374  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+164) (BuildId: f90004a78069fa4c4e587a2081d386cd)
      #54 pc 00000000000d2a71  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+865) (BuildId: f90004a78069fa4c4e587a2081d386cd)
      #55 pc 0000000000002f9f  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1599) (BuildId: 5c47dfdf42370b14f9eaa0b58a1dedf3)
      #56 pc 0000000000050079  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+89) (BuildId: 5db8d317d3741b337ef046540bbdd0f7)
**Lost connection to device.**
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug in Flutter, you can check out the bug[#112542](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112542) on GitHub。

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33471167)